# What does cluster.size do in D3JS?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a graph based on Mike Bostock's Heirarchical Edge Bundling([here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1044242)). I need to make my JSON look as readme-flare-imports.json looks, but I can't figure out what "size" is. I read the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout#wiki-size) and it didn't seem to help me. Also, it will be a dynamic JSON file based on a mySQL database, so I won't be able to set the size myself. Is anybody able to clear things up for me as to what it is or how I may be able to determine what the size should be? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cluster.size` determines how large of an area the cluster will take up. You pass values to it like so

```
// The angle
var x = 360;
// The radius
var y = window.height / 2;
cluster.size([x, y])
```

`x` will determine how much of a circle the cluster will use to branch out children. A value of `360` will use the entire circle to display all values. A value of `180` will only use half the circle to branch out values.

`y` will determine how wide the circle will become in any single direction, i.e., the radius of the circle.

In the Heirarchical Edge Bundling example, I believe the `size` attribute in the `json` file is ignored as I could not find anything in the code that cared about it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll just generate it without that function and hope for the best. I'd upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet.